# Form showing values of last ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery

Multiple forms in a page, form initially shows empty and from next invocation showing values from last AJAX call

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#creationForm").hide();
            $("#create").hide();
       $("#submit").click(function() {
         $("#creationForm").show();
            $("#create").show();
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Ajax call inside javascript function

```
       $.ajax({
                async: false,
                cache: false,
                url: "changeCreation.do",
                method: "post",
                data: {
                    "operationName": "submitButtonClicked",
                    "templateNameVal": templateName
                },
                success: function () {
                }
            });



<form action="changeCreation.do" method="post" id="myForm">
  <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit"
                    onclick="submitButton()">Submit</button>
</form>

 <form action="changeCreation.do" method="post" id="creationForm"
---contains a lot of fields that should be populated after ajax call
</form>
```

Code in servlet

```
if (operationName != null && operationName.equals("submitButtonClicked")) {

                TemplateBean tbean = null;
            try {
                if (templateName != null) {

                   //DB call
                    tbean = service.getTemplateDetail(templateName, request);
                    if (tbean != null) {
                        tbean.setTemplateName(templateName);
                    }
                } 
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
            }
            session.setAttribute("templateBean", tbean);

        }
```

The form creationForm is not showing the values corresponding to a template name selected from a dropdown in myForm

Form is showing values corresponding to selection1 while selecting selection2 from dropdown

Comment: You have submit button inside `myForm` so on click of button only `myForm` details will be submitted

Comment: Would making the second from as div help? cause what I am trying to achieve is basically on submit from form 1, name selected from drop down fetches values from db that are to be displayed on form2. Form 2 is showing erratic values now

Answer (score 0):

You have submit button inside `myForm` and hence after click on button it is submitting `myForm` form instead of `creationForm`. Do following changes in your code -

HTML: remove `type="submit"` from the button

```
<form action="changeCreation.do" method="post" id="myForm">
  <button id="submit" name="submit"
                    onclick="submitButton()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

jQuery : submit the form explicitly and remove default behavior of button click

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#creationForm").hide();
            $("#create").hide();
       $("#submit").click(function(e) {
         e.preventDefault(); // remove default behavior of button submit
         $("#creationForm").show();
            $("#create").show();
            $("#creationForm").submit(); // submit the form with id
        });
    });
```

Comment: This does not solve my purpose. I am not having form submission issue. on click of submit button, submit button function is called which contains the ajax call followed by document ready onclick to show form populated with values, however the values being populated look like cached values